# Why does a proprety call {{hero.name}} work in a <h> but not in a <img>

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

In the template, the following code works normally:

```
<h3>{{hero.name}}</h3>
```

or even:

```
<a routerLink="/details/{{hero.id}}">{{hero.name}}</a>
```

But when it comes to the following image path:

```
<img [src]="'/pictures/{{hero.name}}' | getDownloadURL" />
```

It is interpreted as a string, as in the error message:

> ERROR FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object 'pictures/{{hero.name}}'
> does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)

Even though the picture is accessible through:

```
<img [src]="'/pictures/mario' | getDownloadURL" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

> <img [src]="'/pictures/' + hero.name | getDownloadURL" />

Answer (score 0):

Use template strings in such cases:
`/pictures/${hero.name} | getDownloadURL`

Answer (score -1):

try to use `` quotes

"`/pictures/{{hero.name}} | getDownloadURL"

Comment: It returns an error:

Comment: Parser Error: Unexpected token Lexer Error: Unexpected character [`] at column 1 in expression [`/pictures/{{hero.name}}` | getDownloadURL] at column 2 in [`/pictures/{{hero.name}}` | getDownloadURL] in c:/Users/Youce/exam7/src/app/hero-details/hero-details.component.html@16:17